# how to close this file to rename and delete a file("Stream closed")

Tags: java, while-loop, file-rename, txt

Hi I am having trouble deleting and renaming my file this is because my file is still open but when I try to close my file I then get a `stream closed`  which means my file is closed, my question how do I get my code to delete and rename my file even though my file stream is closed, all my txt files are in the correct folder

```
public static void updateRecord(int recordID, int recordColumnIndex, String newValue,String fileName) throws IOException {
        java.io.PrintWriter writer;
        try (java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(fileName))) {
            writer = new java.io.PrintWriter("temp.txt");
            String line;
            // Read file line by line...
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    writer.println(line);
                    continue;
                }
                // Split each read line to separate data.
                String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");

            /* If the record ID value matches the supplied ID value
               then make the desired changes to that line.    */
                if (Integer.parseInt(lineParts[0]) == recordID) {
                    lineParts[recordColumnIndex] = newValue;
                    // Rebuild the data line...
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(recordID));
                    for (int i = 1; i < lineParts.length; i++) {
                        sb.append(",").append(lineParts[i]);
                    }
                    line = sb.toString();
                }
                writer.println(line);  // write line to `temp.tmp` file.
                writer.flush();        // Immediate write.
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        writer.close();

        File inputFile = new File("tasks.txt");
        File outFile = new File("temp.txt");

        if (inputFile.exists()) {
            Files.delete(Path.of("tasks.txt"));
            outFile.renameTo(inputFile);
            System.out.println("test");
        }else{
            System.out.println("error");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check that you haven't opened same file in other code. What is the actual exception and stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem most likely is caused elsewhere - check all file I/O operations. I suggest you tidy your code so that the file handling is clearer, consistently using NIO `Path` and `Files`, not repeating filename definitions, and that all streams are closed using try-with-resources handling:

```
public static void updateRecord(int recordID, int recordColumnIndex, String newValue, Path fileName) throws IOException {

    Path tempOutFile = Path.of("temp.txt");
    Path mainInputFile = Path.of("tasks.txt");

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(fileName);
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(tempOutFile))) {

        ...
    }
    // Replace main file:
    Files.deleteIfExists(mainInputFile);
    Files.move(tempOutFile, mainInputFile);
}
```